# How to get top X number of items according to a property in a paginated API?

Tags: mysql, algorithm, api, rest, endpoint

**Please note the question is purposely vague.**
Assume, I have an API that returns paginated data of books. 100 book objects per page [This data is present in the headers like 'total-pages'. The response body is in the format of a list of JSON objects.

```
[
 {},
 {},
  .
  .
  .
]
```

Assume book object has all the necessary data such as title, description, number of sales, etc, and so on. How do I return top-selling n number of books [top-selling => Highest number of sales]?
You cannot provide any parameters such as

```
GET endpoint/orderby=popularity&order=desc
```

to this endpoint and you cannot make any database query optimizations. How do we solve this problem with just pure code?
I'll be grateful for any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: So your problem has nothing to do with the rest endpoint, as the ordering has to be done *after* you have received the data. Therefore, provide a snippet with sample data, and what you have tried. Note: this sounds like a duplicate question. There are many Q&A on how to sort an object array.

Comment: my idea was to store everything in a max-heap and return the first 100. @trincot

Comment: Yes, that would work. Did you try?

Comment: Currently, it works, but I was hoping somebody could share a more efficient solution.

Comment: If you have working code, and are asking a review about its efficiency, code style, ...etc, consider preparing a suitable question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If however, you have a problem with your code, this is the right place, but you should post your code and pinpoint what exactly is the problem.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say, but I am asking for a solution that is different from 1) store in array and sort or 2) use max heap and return 1st 100.

Comment: "RESTful" does not tell us what options are available in the API.

Comment: @RickJames the purpose of mentioning "RESTful' was for familiarity. However, in the question, I have mentioned the things that can be and cannot be done. To avoid confusion, I have removed that phrase. The question is vague for a purpose.

Comment: Vague questions aren't allowed here, even if it's vague on purpose. Also, Stack Overflow questions should have answers, not just ideas or suggestions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [real questions have answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the endpoint is limited in the parameters it accepts, your only option is to fetch all the pages (by continuously looping until it errors) and then sort it in your program it self.

If the above solution is slow, you can optimize by relaxing your requirements from `return top-selling n number of books` to `return a few top-selling books which are in the top X%`

Comment: My idea was similar to yours. Using a maxheap and returning 1st 100. Can you elaborate more return top-selling n number of books to return a few top-selling books which are in the top X%